# Cannot figure out how to format scanner input to two decimal places without getting this error

Tags: java, formatting

Can someone lead me in the right direction or help me figure out why it's giving me the error of "100.0Exception in thread "main" 310.93 degrees in Fahrenheit isjava.util.MissingFormatArgumentException: Format specifier '%7.2f'? I'm a beginner in Java and can't seem to find a fix for this issue.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Below this comment: declare and instantiate a Scanner
          
          
        // Below this comment: declare any other variables you may need
        // to store the user's input and the Kelvin equivalent value
        

        // Below this comment: collect the requried inputs from the user
        System.out.println("Enter temperature in Fahrenheit : ");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        float fahr = scan.nextFloat();
        // Below this comment: call your FahrenheitToKelvin method
        FahrenheitToKelvin(fahr);

        // Below this comment: disply the required results
        System.out.printf(fahr + "%.2f" + " degrees in Fahrenheit is%7.2f", FahrenheitToKelvin(fahr));
        System.out.printf(" degrees in Kelvin. ");
              
       }
       
       // define your FahrenheitToKelvin method here below
       public static float FahrenheitToKelvin(float fahr) {
          float kelv = (float) ((fahr - 32) * 5/9 + 273.15);
          return kelv;
      
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because in your `printf` you have 2 format specifiers (`%.2f` and `%7.2f`) and only one value (the result from `FahrenheitToKelvin(fahr)`).

Your code

```java
System.out.printf(fahr + "%.2f" + " degrees in Fahrenheit is%7.2f", FahrenheitToKelvin(fahr));
```

has 3 strings, the `fahr` variable (which is a float, but gets converted here for the output because you concatenate it to a String), the `"%.2f"`, and the `" degrees in Fahrenheit is %7.2f"`. These get combined to one String before `printf` is called, e.g., to `"123%.2f degrees Fahrenheit is %7.2f"` if you enter 123. Now `printf` parses the String and sees two `%` markers for variables, but gets only the result of `FahrenheitToKelvin(fahr)` passed after the format string, and hence it throws an Exception which in turn crashes your program.

You can either just concatenate all numbers like this:

```java
System.out.printf(fahr + " degrees in Fahrenheit is " + FahrenheitToKelvin(fahr));
```

and then also just use `println` instead of `printf`.

Or you can pass both numbers to `printf`, so that the number of `%` format specifiers matches the number of arguments:

```java
System.out.printf("%.2f" + " degrees in Fahrenheit is%7.2f", fahr, FahrenheitToKelvin(fahr));
```

or, simpler and with a space before printing the result for legibility:

```java
System.out.printf("%.2f degrees Fahrenheit is %7.2f degrees Kelvin", fahr, FahrenheitToKelvin(fahr));
```